# Cannot change color for the character in TASM

Tags: assembly, colors, x86-16, tasm

[image]

[TASM code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2nnC.png)

I added the instruction `mov bl,178` under `mov dl,42` but cannot change the color of the character. How should I do if I want to change the color of the characters?
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8bFs.png)

[image]

Comment: @fuz here is the new question. Thanks for your help

Comment: Do not post picture of code. Anyway, int21/02 does not take a color.

Comment: Please provide code without image

Answer (score 1):

### DOS doesn't do color, but BIOS does.

You can use the BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute function 09h.

```
mov cx, 1       ; ReplicationCount
mov bx, 00B2h   ; BH DisplayPage 0, BL Attribute 178
mov ax, 092Ah   ; AH Function 09h, AL Character 42
int 10h
```

Different from the DOS function 02h is that the cursor did not advance. To that effect you can append the BIOS.Teletype function 0Eh

```
mov cx, 1       ; ReplicationCount
mov bx, 00B2h   ; BH DisplayPage 0, BL Attribute 178
mov ax, 092Ah   ; AH Function 09h, AL Character 42
int 10h
mov ah, 0Eh
int 10h
```